# Many simultaneous INSERTs - best strategy?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am planning an application with many mobile devices which periodically connect to SQL server and send INSERTs to a table in 100-record chunks, wrapped in a transaction (100-record chunks are used to minimize network overhead as inserting record by record is very slow). There can be up to 20-30 devices sending data at the same time. Question, for which I cannot find no clear answer is - is SQL Server blocking target table until single transaction is committed (so the other devices have to wait) or multiple transactions are run in parallel? Tests currently show that table is blocked until transaction is committed, which sometimes result in timeout errors on device. Does setting transaction level to "read uncommitted" makes any difference for INSERT statements? (I don't care about "dirty reads").

Comment: 1 - If you are taking that long to insert 100 records, you are almost certainly doing it wrong. If you are doing this 1 row at a time, you probably need to convert your logic to use the MERGE command (2008+)

Comment: Gary, when application gets to insertion, it happens fast, a second at most for those 100 records. The problem, as how it seems now, are clients "queuing" and waiting for their transaction to start and then dying with timeout errors.

Comment: Taking 1 second to insert 100 records is very very slow as for a set based operation. You question is unclear, is each of the connections sending thousands of record that are batched in 100 record chunks, or is each of the connections send 100 record chunks.

Comment: Gary, first case - there are 20-30 devices each having up to 1500 records and sending data in 100-record chunks, wrapped in transaction

Comment: Does your record insertion have triggers or lots of indices to maintain? You may have a problem that your data is bursty. And it may be than 45K records per second may be exceeding your design (though that should not really be an problem). You could create a staging table (or set of staging tables) that are low overhead (no triggers, minimum index) and accept the blocks of data quickly with a separate work moving the staged data to the final location. Still, 100 records taking  < 1 second seem very slow, I can't but think this is really your root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stop breaking up your 1500 record batches into 100 record batches. Insert all 1500 records using a single Bulk Insert statement. This is almost certain to be the fastest method. If you can't use this approach, you should explain why